# Detect multiple control changed in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

how can I control some controls that will be created automatically during the execution of the application?

My add control

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Dim NewCheckbox As CheckBox
   For i As Integer = 2 To 14
                NewCheckbox = New CheckBox
                NewCheckbox.Size = New Drawing.Size(15, 14)
                NewCheckbox.Location = New Point(98, 40)
                NewCheckbox.Name = "cbcard" & i
    Me.Controls.Add(NewCheckbox)
    next
```

My checkbox control add, I gave an example to create a checkbox control, but it should be valid for any form of control, be it textbox or button.

how can i detect these controls that are not created but will be created during execution?
checkbox name will be `cbcard1`, `cbcard2`, `cbcard3` up to 14.

but I want this to be in the form of a handler, or it should probably work with a timer.

```
  Private Sub Checkbox_Changed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Checkbox.Changed
            If Checkbox.checked = true
                MsgBox("")
            End If
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the event using the [`AddHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement) syntax.

```vb
For i As Integer = 2 To 14
    NewCheckbox = New CheckBox
    NewCheckbox.Size = New Drawing.Size(15, 14)
    NewCheckbox.Location = New Point(98, 40)
    NewCheckbox.Name = "cbcard" & i
    Me.Controls.Add(NewCheckbox)

   'subscribe to the CheckChanged event (as an example)
   AddHandler NewCheckbox.CheckChanged, AddressOf Checkbox_Changed
Next

'all dynamically created checkboxes were subscribed to this event
Private Sub Checkbox_Changed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'sender is the specific checkbox that was changed out of all subscribed checkboxes
    Dim checkBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
    If checkbox.checked = true Then MsgBox(checkBox.Name)
End Sub
```

Comment: I corrected the typo of `AddHandler NewChecbox` to `AddHandler NewCheckbox` for you. Your answer would be better if you put the `Dim NewCheckbox As CheckBox` inside the For loop to restrict its scope, and mentioned that it's best to minimise the scope of variables.